# I want to run code on data frame up to a certain date (column 2)

Tags: r

I am trying to run code on a data frame up to a certain date. I have individual game statistics, the second column is Date in order. I thought this is how to do this however I get an error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(dfmess, dfmess$Date <= Standingdate) : 
   undefined columns selected
```

Here is my code:

```
read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1516/E0.csv")

dfmess <- read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1516/E0.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Standingdate <- as.Date("09/14/15", format = "%m/%d/%y")
dfmess[dfmess$Date <= Standingdate] -> dfmess
```

Comment: Read `help("[")`. Your code is missing a `,`.

Comment: I read it. Still don't know where the , goes? Only been using R a few days.
Do you mean dfmess[dfmess$Date <= Standingdate, ] -> dfmess

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. It does not give an error however when I run dfmess I still get the entire dataframe. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to convert `dfmess$Date` to `as.Date` first prior to comparing. In addition, per @Roland's comment, you require an additional comma `,`:

```
dfmess <- read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1516/E0.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dfmess$Date <- as.Date(dfmess$Date, "%m/%d/%y")
Standingdate <- as.Date("09/14/15", format = "%m/%d/%y")
dfmess[dfmess$Date <= Standingdate, ]
```